# Android Keyboard - Build LatinIME and Package w/ libjni_latinime.so

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-source

I ran a sync on the master AOSP branch so I could compile and build a custom version of LatinIME.  I made my changes to the `LatinIME.java` file and ran a `make LatinIME` to compile.  I ran it with an emluator first and it was fine because I was able to make sure that `libjni_latinime.so` was in the `/system/lib/` directory.

Now that I am ready to move it to my device - an Galaxy S5 G900V (Verizon) w/ 5.0 (L) - NOT rooted.

I installed the .apk file that was generated but I am getting errors because I have no way of putting `libjni_latinime.so` on to the device without rooting it.

Is there any way to include `libjni_latinime.so` with LatinIME.apk or some other way to get this to work without rooting my device?  I just can't find any resources on this and I really don't want to have to root my device just to move this file over to /system/lib/..

Thanks in advance!

If the crash logs help at all, here they are. This is what generates when I install the APK and try to open the keyboard:

```
 03-10 19:06:10.578: E/art(10652): No implementation found for long com.android.inputmethod.latin.BinaryDictionary.createOnMemoryNative(long, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String[]) (tried Java_com_android_inputmethod_latin_BinaryDictionary_createOnMemoryNative and Java_com_android_inputmethod_latin_BinaryDictionary_createOnMemoryNative__JLjava_lang_String_2_3Ljava_lang_String_2_3Ljava_lang_String_2)
03-10 19:06:10.578: E/AndroidRuntime(10652): FATAL EXCEPTION: Executor - UserHistoryDictionary.en_US
03-10 19:06:10.578: E/AndroidRuntime(10652): Process: com.android.inputmethod.latin, PID: 10652
03-10 19:06:10.578: E/AndroidRuntime(10652): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long com.android.inputmethod.latin.BinaryDictionary.createOnMemoryNative(long, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String[]) (tried Java_com_android_inputmethod_latin_BinaryDictionary_createOnMemoryNative and Java_com_android_inputmethod_latin_BinaryDictionary_createOnMemoryNative__JLjava_lang_String_2_3Ljava_lang_String_2_3Ljava_lang_String_2)
03-10 19:06:10.578: E/AndroidRuntime(10652):    at com.android.inputmethod.latin.BinaryDictionary.createOnMemoryNative(Native Method)
03-10 19:06:10.578: E/AndroidRuntime(10652):    at com.android.inputmethod.latin.BinaryDictionary.<init>(BinaryDictionary.java:157)
03-10 19:06:10.578: E/AndroidRuntime(10652):    at com.android.inputmethod.latin.ExpandableBinaryDictionary.createOnMemoryBinaryDictionaryLocked(ExpandableBinaryDictionary.java:260)
03-10 19:06:10.578: E/AndroidRuntime(10652):    at com.android.inputmethod.latin.ExpandableBinaryDictionary.createNewDictionaryLocked(ExpandableBinaryDictionary.java:561)
03-10 19:06:10.578: E/AndroidRuntime(10652):    at com.android.inputmethod.latin.ExpandableBinaryDictionary.access$700(ExpandableBinaryDictionary.java:53)
03-10 19:06:10.578: E/AndroidRuntime(10652):    at com.android.inputmethod.latin.ExpandableBinaryDictionary$12.run(ExpandableBinaryDictionary.java:605)
03-10 19:06:10.578: E/AndroidRuntime(10652):    at com.android.inputmethod.latin.ExpandableBinaryDictionary$1.run(ExpandableBinaryDictionary.java:194)
03-10 19:06:10.578: E/AndroidRuntime(10652):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-10 19:06:10.578: E/AndroidRuntime(10652):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-10 19:06:10.578: E/AndroidRuntime(10652):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
03-10 19:06:10.588: V/ApplicationPolicy(1027): isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname com.android.inputmethod.latin
03-10 19:06:10.598: E/art(10652): No implementation found for long com.android.inputmethod.latin.BinaryDictionary.createOnMemoryNative(long, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String[]) (tried Java_com_android_inputmethod_latin_BinaryDictionary_createOnMemoryNative and Java_com_android_inputmethod_latin_BinaryDictionary_createOnMemoryNative__JLjava_lang_String_2_3Ljava_lang_String_2_3Ljava_lang_String_2)
```

Comment: In Eclipse you just put the .so file in your libs/<appropriate_abi> folder and it will be included.  I assume android studio has something similar.

Comment: Building LatinIME in Eclipse or Android Studio is much more difficult due to the amount of dependencies. I have not found a solid resource on how to even do it - only how to run a `make` on the master branch and build it that way. I get my LatinIME.apk file and my libjni_latinime.so file, just no method of getting libjni_latinime.so to my /system/lib/ folder..

Comment: If you just need it on your device and you're rooted, you can do an adb push.  If that doesn't work you can push it to the device, adb shell, su, then remount the system drive to read write and copy it to the right location.

Comment: I'm not rooted - that is my #1 problem. And because I am on 5.0, I would have to factory reset, root, and not update again. Which is a huge pain. There has to be a way to compile this package with a library and not have to manually copy the file to a readonly directory

Comment: You should be able to include the library just as with a 3rd party SDK app.  If really stuck on the build process, package that library with a *dummy* sdk app and then copy the resulting library folders from that apk (as a zip file) to your real one, strip the signatures, align, and sign.  The only question which you may need to resolve is if the system searches the system library path before an app's - if that is the case and there is already an old copy there, you should rename your library and change the name where it is loaded from Java. Or maybe there is already a copy which is the same.

Comment: I have tried including the library separately but it didn't work. I decompiled "Google Keyboard" using APKtool and inserted my altered smali files and I got "malformed manifest" errors at installation. Now I am trying to build LatinIME within Android Studio. I will update if I can get that to work (sooo many dependencies I have to worry about..)

Comment: @burmat Have you been able to build the file?

Comment: @VipulKumar yes I was able to do it but I don't remember how - it was a long time ago.  I would have to dig up the old project and get back to you. Drop me an email if you want.

Comment: @burmat Thanks. I made it work.

Comment: @burmat can you help me regarding this. I was able to build but it crashes as soon I open it.